# ionic deploy build version or hash

Tags: ionic-framework

I am integrating Ionic Deploy Service on one of my apps built with ionic framework.

I am looking if it is possible to get the build version when checking for new update. Actually, the check function is only returning a true/false response if there is an update or not. What I am looking for is to get a build version or such an id or hash that identify the new build.

Please any solution on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `Ionic.Deploy().info()` (see [here](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/deploy-usage#section-getting-deploy-info)) which provides the **deploy UUID** and the binary version of the latest updated *deployed on the device*.

Javascript :

```
var deploy = new Ionic.Deploy();
deploy.info().then(function(deployInfo) {
  // deployInfo will be a JSON object that contains
  // information relating to the latest update deployed
  // on the device
}, function() {}, function() {});
```

(just for the sake of the explanation, here's the [native source code](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-deploy/blob/c48dd70b7705305f8ae26fb43cb892e2b719eeeb/src/android/IonicDeploy.java#L269) (Android))

```
private void info(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {
        json.put("deploy_uuid", this.getUUID());
        json.put("binary_version", this.deconstructVersionLabel(this.version_label)[0]);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        callbackContext.error("Unable to gather deploy info: " + e.toString());
    }

    callbackContext.success(json);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was expecting to find such a function, I don't know why I couldn't find it before.

Comment: is it possible to get the info of the new build (next one to be installed). The info() function is returning the last deployed one, but not the comming one.

Comment: I assume you'll have to edit the plugin source code for that... I saw no such feature in the official doc/API.

Have a look at [this part](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-deploy/blob/c48dd70b7705305f8ae26fb43cb892e2b719eeeb/src/android/IonicDeploy.java#L310) (Android) and [this one](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-deploy/blob/master/src/ios/IonicDeploy.m#L144) (iOs). This is where the update uuid is available (read directly from the JSON response of the ionic.io API). 

You could also create a Pull Request on their GitHub but the team looks pretty busy with ionic 2 these days

Comment: You may pass the update uuid as a second parameter (the first is the boolean) of the "check" method (the one you use with Javascript).

Comment: The API endpoint is `/api/v1/apps/" + this.app_id + "/updates/check/"` and it requires **current** UUID and Deploy Channel as parameters. You can get both these details (uuid & channel) using the JavaScript API. You also know your `app_id`. Thus I assume you could ask the API these JSON details on your own (without changing the plugin native code). 

However, as you probably already know, that's not *safe* and should not be done in production.